# How to count the number of letters in each row using r?

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I want to count how many specific letters occur in each row.

```
countedAA <- data.frame (c('A count','C count','D count','E
    count','F count','G count','H count','I count','K count','L
    count','M count','N count','P count','Q count','R count','S
    count','T count','V count','W count','Y count'))

file <- data.frame (c('A,'V','S','A','V'),
                    c('S','K','I','C','A'),
                    c('D','G','R','S','W'))
```

e.g. the expected result for the first example:

```
'A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y
 2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  2,  0,  0
```

This is what I've tried:

```
count_aa1 <- file %>%
            rowSums() ~
                               c(sum('A'),
                                 sum('C'),
                                 sum('D'),
                                 sum('E'),
                                 sum('F'),
                                 sum('G'),
                                 sum('H'),
                                 sum('I'),
                                 sum('K'),
                                 sum('L'),
                                 sum('M'),
                                 sum('N'),
                                 sum('P'),
                                 sum('Q'),
                                 sum('R'),
                                 sum('S'),
                                 sum('T'),
                                 sum('V'),
                                 sum('W'),
                                 sum('Y'))
          view(count_aa1)
          results <- cbind(countedAA, count_aa1) 
          results
```

I get this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame
```

I would be grateful for your suggestions!

Comment: Your code is not reproducable. If you copy-paste your `countedAA` line you get an odd data frame that does not seem to be what you want. If you copy-paste your `file <- ...` line there is a syntax error (missing quote). and the data frame populates by column and not by row. Very unclear what your expected output is when there are multiple rows (should the output be a table, 1 row per input row ?)

Comment: The input data has a lot of issues and very difficult to understand the structure of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of issues in your input data and it is not clear what is the exact structure of the data that you have. I have fixed few of them to provide an answer here.

You can gather all the unique values that you want to count by removing additional text in them using `gsub`. Use `table` to count frequency for each letter.

```
unique_values <- gsub('count|\\s', '', countedAA$a)
unique_values
#[1] "A" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "K" "L" "M" "N" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "V" "W" "Y"

apply(file, 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique_values)))

#  a b c
#A 2 1 0
#C 0 1 0
#D 0 0 1
#E 0 0 0
#F 0 0 0
#G 0 0 1
#H 0 0 0
#I 0 1 0
#K 0 1 0
#L 0 0 0
#M 0 0 0
#N 0 0 0
#P 0 0 0
#Q 0 0 0
#R 0 0 1
#S 1 1 1
#T 0 0 0
#V 2 0 0
#W 0 0 1
#Y 0 0 0
```

The way your data was set up seemed like you want to count the frequency in each column (instead of row) hence, I am using `apply` with `margin = 2`. If you want to do it for each row use apply with `margin = 1`.

**data**

```
countedAA <- data.frame (a = c('A count','C count','D count','E count','F count',
'G count','H count','I count','K count','L count','M count','N count','P count','Q count',
'R count','S  count','T count','V count','W count','Y count'))

file <- data.frame(a = c('A','V','S','A','V'),
                   b = c('S','K','I','C','A'),
                   c =  c('D','G','R','S','W'))
```